# Difference between XML files for a specific tag

Tags: python, xml

I want to find all differences between two XML files for a specific tag.

I have the two following files :

file1.xml

```xml
<customerList>
    <customer name="John" age="23" country="France" />
    <customer name="Jack" age="35" country="Spain" />
    <customer name="Will" age="58" country="Japan" />
</customerList>
```

file2.xml

```xml
<customerList>
    <customer name="John" age="24" country="France" />
    <customer name="Jack" age="35" country="England" />
    <customer name="Tom" age="45" country="Chili" />
</customerList>
```

I want to compare datas from tag customer.name

I tried to use xmldiff Python as following:

```
  formatter = formatting.DiffFormatter()
  diff = main.diff_files(file1,file2,formatter=formatter)
  print(diff)
```

I obtain this result:

```
[update-attribute, /customerList/customer[1], age, "24"]
[update-attribute, /customerList/customer[2], country, "England"]
[update-attribute, /customerList/customer[3], age, "45"]
[update-attribute, /customerList/customer[3], country, "Chili"]
[update-attribute, /customerList/customer[3], name, "Tom"]
```

But I want to compare datas "age" and "country" for a same customer "name" and I expect results as:

- for customer John, "age" has changed (23 vs 24)
- for customer Jack, "country" has changed (Spain vs England)
- customer Tom has been added
- customer Will has been deleted

Do you know the correct configuration of xmldiff to have ? Or do you know another Python module to obtain my expected results?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://xmldiff.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)? Have you seen the `uniqueattrs` option?

Comment: This riddle seems to be a valid(and good) question.

Comment: Hello @gre_gor
I've checked the documentation but I missed this option, I'm really sorry.
Actually, with this option, my problem is solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with xmldiff, but maybe [this code](https://python-forum.io/thread-36089.html) can help you too:

```
from difflib import Differ
from rich import print
 
with open("file1.xml") as f1,open("file2.xml") as f2:
    f_1 = [i.strip() for i in f1]
    f_2 = [i.strip() for i in f2]
 
diff = Differ()
difference = list(diff.compare(f_1, f_2))
difference = '\n'.join(difference)
print(difference)
```

Output:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <customerList>
- <customer name="John" age="23" country="France" />
?                             ^

+ <customer name="John" age="24" country="France" />
?                             ^

- <customer name="Jack" age="35" country="Spain" />
?                                         ^^ -

+ <customer name="Jack" age="35" country="England" />
?                                         ^^^^  +

- <customer name="Will" age="58" country="Japan" />
?                 ^^^^        -           ^^^^^

+ <customer name="Tom" age="45" country="Chili" />
?                 ^^^       +            ^^^^^

  </customerList>
```

For a single xml object you can do something, like:

```
from difflib import Differ
from rich import print
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

j1 = ET.parse("file1.xml").getroot().find('.//customer[@name="John"]')
j2 = ET.parse("file2.xml").getroot().find('.//customer[@name="John"]')
 
diff = Differ()
difference = diff.compare(ET.tostring(j1).decode(),ET.tostring(j2).decode())
difference = ''.join(difference)
print(difference)
```